# Any idea how I can loop through an array, in a batch file, getting info based on each value?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, count, filepath

I am creating a batch file that will gather information (size, number of files and number of folders) based on a pathway in an array from an external text file.  At the minute, I am able to get these details but I am only getting the information for the last pathway listed in the text file.

Here's what I've go so far:

```
::Title for the cmd window
TITLE Getting Repository information
ECHO OFF
::Setting parameters
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set today=!date:/=-!
::Setting the location of the output file
set output=!C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\output_!today!.txt!
set pathway=!C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pathways.txt!
ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------>> !output!
ECHO ----------Time to get some repository information:---------->> !output!
ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!
ECHO %date% %time%>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!
::Creating an array
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for /F %%a in (C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pathways.txt) do (
  set /A i+=1
  set array[!i!]=%%a
)
set n=%i%
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (set folder=!array[%%i]!)
::Getting the repository size (only displays the size info for the location of this file)
ECHO OFF
Set _size=0
For /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%I In ('Dir %folder% /a-d /S ^|Find /I "file(s)"') Do Set _size=%%I
ECHO %folder% %_size% Bytes>> !output!
::Getting the number of folders
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad %folder%^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
ECHO %folder% %count% folder(s^)>> !output!
::Getting the number of files
set /a count=0 
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/s/b/a-d %folder%') do ( 
set /a count+=1 
) 
ECHO %folder% %count% file(s)>> !output!
ECHO ============================================================>> !output!
ECHO ============================================================>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!
```

Sorry for it being messy.  I can't indent it nicely. I am probably overlooking something.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: double the % signs to escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::Title for the cmd window
TITLE Getting Repository information
ECHO OFF

::Setting parameters
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set today=!date:/=-!

::Setting the location of the output file
set output=!C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\output_!today!.txt!
set pathway=!C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pathways.txt!
ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------>> !output!
ECHO ----------Time to get some repository information:---------->> !output!
ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!
ECHO %date% %time%>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!
ECHO.>> !output!

::Creating an array
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for /F %%a in (C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pathways.txt) do (
  set /A i+=1
  set array[!i!]=%%a
)
set n=%i%
REM APA - Next line get LAST array element only and process it:
REM for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (set folder=!array[%%i]!)
REM To process all folders, nest the following process into this FOR loop
REM and change all %var% by !var! for vars assigned into the loop:

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
   set folder=!array[%%i]!

   ::Getting the repository size (only displays the size info for the location of this file^)
   ECHO OFF
   Set _size=0
   For /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%I In ('Dir !folder! /a-d /S ^|Find /I "file(s^)"') Do Set _size=%%I
   ECHO !folder! !_size! Bytes>> !output!

   ::Getting the number of folders
   for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad !folder!^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
   ECHO !folder! !count! folder(s^)>> !output!

   ::Getting the number of files
   set /a count=0 
   for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/s/b/a-d !folder!') do ( 
      set /a count+=1 
   )

   ECHO !folder! !count! file(s^)>> !output!
   ECHO ============================================================>> !output!
   ECHO ============================================================>> !output!
   ECHO.>> !output!

rem The FOR loop ends here:
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work either @Aacini.  I am only getting as far as the date printed, nothing more.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to escape the right parentheses inside the new `for` loop. Fixed...

Answer (score 1):

This line will set folder to the last item in the array, only.

Move the closing parenthesis to the end of your next code section.

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (set folder=!array[%%i]!)
```

Comment: This won't display any information.  If I place the closing parenthesis after gathering the number of files part, it just prints out a space followed by "file(s" three times (the number of pathways in the text file.  If I move the parenthesis after finding the number of size sections or folders, I just get a space followed by "Bytes" or "folder(s)" and the number of files in the last pathway in the text file.  Is there another way around this that you know off?  Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: That's the problem.  As it stands it will set the `folder` variable to the last element in the array, represented by %n% anyway. Put `&echo !folder!&pause` just inside the last closing parenthesis and run it.

Comment: Unfortunately that is giving me the same results. :(

Comment: It should have echoed the `folder` variable for each element of the array, and paused after each one - did it not do that?

Comment: Yes it done that, but when outputting it to the text file, I got the same results as before.  I now have a solution (see above).  Thanks for your help and time!